# Undefined and Null in *NgIf

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

Are `null`, `undefined` and `""<empty string>` value treated similarly by *Ngif?
For example, is this:
`*ngIf = "foo == null"`

Treated the same as:
`*ngIf = "foo == undefined"`

If not, is there a simpler way to use *ngIf to not show properties with the value null, undefined, and ""?

Comment: Hey, `foo` itself considered a `false` **value**, use it directly *ngIF="foo"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check *ngIf = "foo" that can check undefined and null or empty.

Comment: Sorry if I sound super ignorant, I'm a beginner in the world of coding. Is "foo" like a function? I thought it was simply a variable people like to use haha

Comment: Ow wait. I think I get what you mean now. Thanks!

Comment: Depends on how you are using it... I considered it as a variable.

Comment: @MartinPascual if it solves your problem then accept the answer also.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this also by using

```
null === undefined // false
null == undefined // true
```

by the use of strict comparison operator